# return single row in stored procedure on oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm using php & oracle.
How can i return a row in stored procedure to be used just like a select query so that I can read them into php.
For example

```
declare or replace procedure select_row 
(
bookingid in integer,
result out varchar2
) as 
begin
select * into result from booking where booking.id = bookingid;
end;
```

Comment: Take away "into result".

Comment: No, the `into result` must be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select a specific field to put into result if you are going to use it like that.

```
declare or replace procedure select_row 
(
    bookingid in integer,
    result out varchar2
) as 
begin
    select booking_name into result from booking where booking.id = bookingid;
end;
```

Otherwise you will need to create an object type first, and select multiple fields into the object type and return that.  You'd have to CREATE OBJECT or CREATE RECORD.

```
CREATE OBJECT BOOKING_OBJ AS (
     bookingid INTEGER
    ,booking_name VARCHAR2(128)
);

declare or replace procedure select_row 
(
    bookingid in integer,
    result out BOOKING_OBJ
) as 
begin
    select booking_obj(bookingid, booking_name) into result from booking where booking.id = bookingid;
end;
```

Or...

```
CREATE TYPE BOOKING_REC as record(
    bookingid integer,
    booking_name varchar2(100)
);

declare or replace procedure select_row 
(
    bookingid in integer,
    result out BOOKING_REC
) as 
begin
    select bookingid, booking_name into result from booking where booking.id = bookingid;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can return a ref cursor.