# Return Single Row In Oracle Function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, stored-functions

I'm attempting to return a single row of user data from a function based on the input of a user. I cannot access the values of the object columns. I have tried the procedure solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772688/return-single-row-in-stored-procedure-on-oracle) as well as pretty much copying the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779735/oracle-plsql-return-one-row-type) (Using ORACLE and SQLDeveloper)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_FINDBYSSN (SSN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN T_USEROBJECT
AS
   THISUSER   T_USEROBJECT;
BEGIN
   SELECT T_USEROBJECT (A.USER_ID,
                        A.FIRSTNAME,
                        A.LASTNAME,
                        A.SOCIAL,
                        A.BIRTHDATE,
                        A.PHONE,
                        A.USER_ROLE_TYPE_ID,
                        A.USER_LOGIN_ID,
                        A.USER_LAST_LOGIN,
                        B.LOGIN_USERNAME,
                        B.LOGIN_PASSWORD)
     INTO THISUSER
     FROM BANK_USERS A
          INNER JOIN LOGININFO B
             ON     A.USER_LOGIN_ID = B.LOGIN_ID
                AND A.SOCIAL = SSN;

   RETURN THISUSER;
END;
/
```

The Object Is A User

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_USEROBJECT IS OBJECT
(
   USERID INTEGER,
   FNAME VARCHAR2 (50),
   LNAME VARCHAR2 (50),
   SSN VARCHAR2 (15),
   BIRTHDATE DATE,
   USERPHONE VARCHAR2 (15),
   ROLEID INT,
   LOGINID INT,
   LASTLOGIN DATE,
   UNAME VARCHAR2 (50),
   UPASS VARCHAR (50)
);
/
```

This outputs [T_USEROBJECT]

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT F_FINDBYSSN('123-45-6789') AS THISUSER FROM DUAL );
```

Using any column names in the select statement causes an "invalid identifier" error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It gives the same [T_USEROBJECT] output actually

Comment: That seems a deficiency of your SQL Developer version. Your code is correct. With the current version I see this: https://i.imgur.com/vhOCRH1.png

Comment: If I double click on the object in the result, I do get this: https://pastebin.com/sWAiejqm. The same result as yourself. But I can't access them when I specify a column name in the select

Comment: So which version of SQL Developer are you using? If it's not the latest, did you try the current one?

Comment: 18.2, which is believe is the latest, no?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm using as well. Maybe something with the configuration

Comment: And you're able to extract the column values in a select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Answer here.
Needed to Use the Treat Function like so

```
SELECT TREAT(THISUSER AS T_USEROBJECT).USERID, TREAT(THISUSER AS T_USEROBJECT).FNAME
 FROM ( SELECT * FROM (SELECT F_FINDBYSSN('123-45-6789') AS THISUSER FROM DUAL ));
```

[How to SELECT from object type column in Oracle 11g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318272/how-to-select-from-object-type-column-in-oracle-11g)

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to do, but is it overkill for retrieving a single row?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_singleuserset IS TABLE OF t_userobject;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_userrow (ssn IN VARCHAR)
   RETURN t_singleuserset
AS
   l_user   t_singleuserset := t_singleuserset ();
   n        INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT a.user_id,
                    a.firstname,
                    a.lastname,
                    a.social,
                    a.birthdate,
                    a.phone,
                    a.user_role_type_id,
                    a.user_login_id,
                    a.user_last_login,
                    b.login_username,
                    b.login_password
               FROM bank_users a
                    INNER JOIN logininfo b
                       ON     a.user_login_id = b.login_id
                          AND a.social = ssn)
   LOOP
      l_user.EXTEND ();
      n := n + 1;
      l_user (n) :=
         t_userobject (i.user_id,
                       i.firstname,
                       i.lastname,
                       i.social,
                       i.birthdate,
                       i.phone,
                       i.user_role_type_id,
                       i.user_login_id,
                       i.user_last_login,
                       i.login_username,
                       i.login_password);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN l_user;
END;
/

SELECT * FROM TABLE (select_userrow ('123-45-6789'));
```